# Change .NET Property Grid readonly attribute at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have a property grid that i wanna change readonly attribute of some of its items at run-time.
Changing readonly for simple items is easy and i have no problem there, my problem is i cannot change readonly for hierarchical items like latitude and longitude in picture below. I even tried to make the whole "Position" category readonly but it didn't seem to help.

[image: hirarchy]

Side question: Is there any way to put some items in a group (like this position item) without wrapping them in a class?

Comment: Good luck. I worked with a co-worker who had to write all kinds of sub-classes to get the behavior I think you're describing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! This could be helpful!

```
public class Member
{
string name;
bool isMarried;
string spouseName;

public string Name
{
get { return name; }
set { name = value; }
}

[System.ComponentModel.RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
public bool IsMarried
{
get { return isMarried; }
set
{
isMarried = value;
bool newValue = !value;
PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType())["SpouseName"];
ReadOnlyAttribute attrib = (ReadOnlyAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)];
FieldInfo isReadOnly = attrib.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
isReadOnly.SetValue(attrib, newValue);
}
}

[ReadOnly(true)]
public string SpouseName
{
get { return spouseName; }
set
{
spouseName = value;
}
}
}
```

Comment: when I run this code readonly of "SpousName" of all instance of "Member" is change!

Comment: Note: Refresh the PropertyGrid for the change to show.